# Create a scatter plot of data which have the same unique ids but are unsorted in r

Tags: r, statistics

I have two data sets which have both the same unique ids, however, they are not sorted according to the unique ids.

Does someone knows how I could plot the data in respect to the unique ids?

Example of the first data set:

```
  Id Results
1 3e 10
2 2  15
3 1c 16
```

Example of the second data set:

```
  Id Results
1 1c 10
2 2  15
3 3e 16
```

Comment: You can check `?order` or convert to `factor` with `levels` specified i.e. `df1$Id <- factor(df1$Id, levels = sort(unique(df1$Id)))` and similarly with `df2`

Comment: You said they have the same Ids, right?  If not, then subset the datasets based on the `intersect` of 'Ids', i.e. `uIds <- intersect(df1$Id, df2$Id); df1S <- subset(df1, Id %in% uIds)` and similarly to `df2`

Comment: yes both data sets of the same unique Id. Its something like measured vs simulated. The Ids exist only once and are the same in numbers as of the other data set. However, there are different sortet, hence when I am plotting a scatter plot, the wrong values are compared with each other plot(x,y).

Comment: True :) just tried to create an example. I have 5234 data points. I imported them in r however, they are differently sorted. Meaning the first unique Id is not the same as in the other data set (here the ID is in the fifth row) now I need to have them the same as in the first data set, so i can plot result one against result two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `merge` to create a single data set where the Ids are aligned and then plot them.

```
df1 = read.table(text="R Id Results
1 3e 10
2 2 15
3 1c 16",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 = read.table(text="R Id Results
1 1c 10
2 2 15
3 3e 16",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Merged = merge(df1[,2:3], df2[,2:3], by="Id")
plot(Merged[,2:3], pch=20)
```

If you really don't like the merged dataset solution,  you can make an index that allows you to look up which Id in df2 matches the Id in df1.

```
df2_index = seq_along(df2)
names(df2_index) = df2$Id
plot(df1$Result, df2$Result[df2_index[df1$Id]], pch=20)
```

Or even simpler is

```
plot(df1$Result, df2$Result[match(df1$Id, df2$Id)], pch=20)
```

Comment: Cool. Did not think of merging them. However, do you know, how I could keep both tables separated? I just would like to have the rows of both tables sorted according to the unique ID. Or at least plot the results in respect to the id and not the row in which they are.

Comment: Adding to answer

Comment: Can not upvote your question. But this was what I was looking for. Thanks again.